# What is the LifeCycle of Thread in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, lifecycle

In java when we create an object of thread

```
Thread t1 = new Thread(Runnable object);
t1.start();
```

What are the different stages of lifecycle of thread `t1` and after execution of `run()` will be the state of `t1`?

Comment: Shows no research effort: search for "java thread life cycle" in a search engine of your choice.

Comment: I would recommend formatting your code if you want to leave this question open. Otherwise I would google "Java Thread documentation" and read through that.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html

Comment: https://www.google.co.in/search?q=What+is+the+LifeCycle+of+Thread+in+Java%3F&oq=What+is+the+LifeCycle+of+Thread+in+Java%3F&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60l2&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: The thread can be interrupted by other threads, So the possible states can be wait,timed wait,sleep or dead

Comment: The question could be a good fit for the documentation as in the SOF. For example, there are 2 answers with good quality images with explanation which is good to understand.

Answer (score 9):

A thread goes through various stages in its life cycle. For example, a thread is born, started, runs, and then dies. Following diagram shows the complete life cycle of a thread.

[image]

Java Thread
Above-mentioned stages are explained here:

`New:` A new thread begins its life cycle in the new state. It remains in this state until the program starts the thread. It is also referred to as a born thread.

`Runnable`: After a newly born thread is started, the thread becomes runnable. A thread in this state is considered to be executing its task.

`Waiting:` Sometimes, a thread transitions to the waiting state while the thread waits for another thread to perform a task.A thread transitions back to the runnable state only when another thread signals the waiting thread to continue executing.

`Timed waiting:` A runnable thread can enter the timed waiting state for a specified interval of time. A thread in this state transitions back to the runnable state when that time interval expires or when the event it is waiting for occurs.

`Terminated ( Dead )`: A runnable thread enters the terminated state when it completes its task or otherwise terminates.

Source:http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_multithreading.htm

Comment: RUNNABLE and RUNNING are distinct states in most operating systems, but there is no `RUNNING` in the `java.lang.Thread.State` enum.  There is only `RUNNABLE`.  A Java thread in the `RUNNABLE` state could either be actually running on a CPU, or it could be waiting for a CPU to run on, but it is not waiting for anything else.

Comment: So, according to the graphic, a “waiting” thread can never become “running” again? That doesn’t match my experience…

Comment: make sure `new Thread();` does not create new thread it just create a simple object.

Comment: How does the interrupted state fit into this?

Answer (score 6):

A thread can be in one of the following [State](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.State.html):

`NEW :`A thread that has not yet started is in this state.

`RUNNABLE :`A thread executing in the Java virtual machine is in this state.

`BLOCKED:`  A thread in the blocked state is waiting for a monitor lock to enter a synchronized block/method or reenter a `synchronized` block/method after calling `Object.wait`.

`WAITING:` A thread that is waiting indefinitely for another thread to perform a particular action is in this state.

A thread is in the waiting state due to calling one of the following methods:

```
Object.wait with no timeout
Thread.join with no timeout
LockSupport.park
```

`TIMED_WAITING:` A thread that is waiting for another thread to perform an action for up to a specified waiting time is in this state.

A thread is in the timed waiting state due to calling one of the following methods with a specified positive waiting time:

```
Thread.sleep
Object.wait with timeout
Thread.join with timeout
LockSupport.parkNanos
LockSupport.parkUntil
```

`TERMINATED:` A thread that has exited is in this state.

Refer to this [article](http://javaconceptoftheday.com/thread-life-cycle-thread-states-java/) by pramodbablad to understand various states in this diagram

[image]

In above diagram, except `RUNNING` ( which has been shown in a circle), all other rectangular blocks denotes various `thread states`.

Answer (score 0):

Thread States:

1. New - Created but not executed
2. Runnable - Running
3. Terminated - End of the Run Method Scope was reached.

A Thread can also have Waiting, Timed Waiting and Blocked as Status

For Further Informations see here:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.State.html