# how to start a thread in Spring bean

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-mvc, dependency-injection, autowired

I want to run a thread in spring application

```
    @Component
    public class MyServiceCreationListener {


        public void startThread() {

            Thread t = new Thread(new MyThread());
            t.start();

        }
    }
```

Here i used `Thread t = new Thread(new MyThread());` This is wrong way.

Please provide solution for this to spring manage MyThread like a spring bean so we can autowire it into other beans and by calling `start()` method we can access it

Here is Thread class

```
@Component
public class MyThread implements Runnable {

    public void run() {

        System.out.println("Inside run()");

    }

}
```

Comment: What does "and by calling start() method we can access it" mean exactly?

Comment: provided solution here not working for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45297652/spring-not-injecting-a-bean-into-thread/45299022?noredirect=1#comment77559847_45299022

Comment: @bowmore means i want to call that thread using start() mehod... sorry for my english :(

Comment: You want each client that gets the thread injected to call start() ? That won't work.

Comment: not by each clients but... anyhow i want to call a thread inside a bean

Answer (score 5):

By default, spring beans are singleton, but Thread's `run` method will only run once. After that it is considered in a state different to RUNNABLE.

[LifeCycle of Thread in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36425942/what-is-the-lifecycle-of-thread-in-java)

So, you need to create a new object every time and you can do that using `prototype` scope and [ObjectFactory](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/ObjectFactory.html).

Extending `Thread`:

```
@Bean
@Scope("prototype")
public class MyThread implements Runnable {

    public void run() {

        System.out.println("Inside run()");

    }
}
```

And then:

```
@Component
public class MyServiceCreationListener {

    @Autowired
    ObjectFactory<MyThread> myThreadFactory;

    public void startThread() {
        myThreadFactory.getObject().start();
    }
}
```

This code has not been tested, it just for you to get an idea.

You can find some examples here: [Spring and java threads](https://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-and-java-thread-example/)

Comment: @Autowired  private MyThread myThread;
will autowire successfully??

Comment: If your configuration is fine it will.

Comment: Have a look now.